# Painting grass on Unity terrain programmability (runtime)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-terrain

I've been having really bad luck finding information and getting getting a working script to paint grass on terrain programmability,
The most common answer I've found goes along this example:

```cs
int[,] newMap = new int[grassDensity, grassDensity];

for (int i = 0; i < grassDensity; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < grassDensity; j++) {
    float height = terrain.terrainData.GetHeight(i, j);
    if (height < 1.0f)
    {
      newMap[i, j] = 1;
    } else {
      newMap[i, j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
terrain.terrainData.SetDetailLayer(15, 15, 0, newMap);
```

But I can't seem to get anything to work, like at all, no results
What currently happens is when a new piece of terrain gets generated as the player walks, It creates a new instance of a ready made GameObject (the chunk in this case), also setting the heights, detail textures, detail layers, etc
Note: the detail textures and detail layers get referenced from a ready made terrain separate to the chunk generation as a attempt to get something working
Want I want is to also 'paint' the detail layer (the grass), it currently doesn't matter about patterns, how often to place the grass, etc. I just want a working way to paint grass on the whole terrain to begin with
*I don't know what extra information to add at this point, if you need more information, please tell me*

I've tried many examples, I've lost track of them, but it goes along the lines of looping through, setting the int array then putting the array into `terrain.terrainData.SetDetailLayer`, I've also tried Alphamaps along side it, even trying to copy detail information directly from a test terrain object

Comment: This just sets the detail layer as you said, but I must ask, is there anything in that detail layer at that point?

Comment: @RyanGray No, nothing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: After a few experiments, it turns out you need to fill the int array first before looping through it, contrary to other code snippets online
So
`int[,] newMap = new int[grassDensity, grassDensity];`
would be:
`int[,] newMap = new int[512, 512];` for a 512x512 Terrain, you could simply use
`t.terrainData.detailWidth, t.terrainData.detailHeight`,
do note with large int arrays, they can take a long time to create, so if the terrain is 1024x1024, expect it to freeze for awhile